# CreateJS working but does not show the Toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, createjs

As the title states I followed their documentation which it not the best for someone new to it or someone who is not that good with jQuery.

My head:

```
<head>
    {{ HTML::script('/themes/admin/js/jquery.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('/themes/admin/js/jquery-ui.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('/themes/admin/js/underscore-min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('/themes/admin/js/vie.js') }}

    {{ HTML::script('/packages/createjs/create.js') }}
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

          jQuery('body').midgardCreate({
            url: function() { return '/admin/content/create'; }
          });

          jQuery('body').midgardToolbar({
            display: 'full'
          });

          jQuery('[about]').midgardEditable({
            vie: new VIE()
          });

        });
      </script>
</head>
```

My editable div under body:

```
<div class="well col-md-3" about="/content/create">
  <div property="content" contenteditable="true">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

This lib seems really good for what I'm trying to implement however there really are not that many resources/tutorials on it.

Comment: I don't know of this matters because I've never used CreateJS, but `about` and `property` are not HTML attributes listed by W3. [See this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a fully working example

http://jsfiddle.net/S9Hgg/5/

In order to understand the exact libraries required.

It is based on the demo found at createjs which is using hallo editor,
http://createjs.org/demo/hallo/

This is the code that starts it up,

```
jQuery('body').midgardCreate({
    url: function() {
      return 'javascript:false;';
    },
    stanbolUrl: 'http://dev.iks-project.eu:8081',
    collectionWidgets: {
      'default': null,
      'feature': 'midgardCollectionAdd'
    }
  });
```

You will find it commented out since your code works too.
It works with jquery1.7.2 and jquery-ui1.8.18, but i think this has to do with the version of hallo. You may experiment with the latest versions and see.

So the dependencies are,

- jquery1.7.2
- jquery-ui1.8.18
- modernizr.custom.80485.js
- underscore-min.js
- backbone-min.js
- vie-min.js
- jquery.rdfquery.min.js
- annotate-min.js
- create.js
- rangy-core-1.2.3.js
- hallo.js
- font-awesome.css
- create-ui.css
- midgardnotif.css
- bootstrap.css
- create-2012.css